# How can I prevent the large mobile banner 320x100 px from sometimes resizing to the 320x50 px mobile leaderboard?

Tags: adsense

I'm using the responsive ad unit and I set the ad unit dimensions to 320x100, but sometimes the 320x50 ad is shown instead, and I am left with an ugly space underneath the ad. I have tried forcing the ad unit to 320x50, but they consistently resize to the 320x100 size. Is there anything I can do to prevent this space under the ads?

[image]

Code used:

HTML:

```
<aside class="advertisement">
    <ins class="adsbygoogle horizontal-ad"
        data-ad-client="ca-pub-000000000"
        data-ad-slot="0000000"
        data-ad-format="horizontal">
    </ins>
    <script>
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
</aside>
```

CSS:

```
.advertisement {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     margin: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
}

.horizontal-ad {
    display: block;
    width: 320px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try `min-height` on your `.advertisement` class. Please see the example below

```css
.advertisement {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     margin: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
     background: yellow;
     min-height: 50px;
}

.horizontal-ad {
    display: block;
    width: 320px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #777;
}
```

```html
<aside class="advertisement">
    <ins class="adsbygoogle horizontal-ad"
        data-ad-client="ca-pub-000000000"
        data-ad-slot="0000000"
        data-ad-format="horizontal">
    </ins>
</aside>
```

Comment: Hi so I tried what you said. The ad is still resizing to 100px tall every time on mobile: https://imgur.com/w1a8zlT

Comment: Have you changed the min-height to somewhat below the standard? Or You can check on developer console, which stylesheet affects the element.